# Sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $n$ is a sum of two squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29441/prove-that-n-is-a-sum-of-two-squares)

I was reading [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67601/which-fibonacci-numbers-are-the-sum-of-two-squares) and began wondering if there is a general theorem that a number of a given form is the sum of two squares. I know about [Fermat's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), but I am thinking about the general case. The question is

> For which positive integer $n$ we can find positive integers $a,b$ with $n=a^2+b^2$?

I found a related question: [Prove that $n$ is a sum of two squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29441/prove-that-n-is-a-sum-of-two-squares)

If this is a duplicate, I am sorry. I have searched the site and didn't find this question posted. Any reference would be useful.

Comment: See [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). It has been said that is the result Fermat was most proud of.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is on the page you linked to: $n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if $n$ is a square times a product of different primes which are either 1 modulo 4 or 2.

Comment: Ok. I'll delete the question. I am sorry I didn't read through the entire post I linked to.

Comment: @amWhy: The answer is not specific, whatever you mean by this. (One considers the number 1 as the empty product, as is usual, and the emptyset is a part of the set of primes. Ergo.)

Comment: Perhaps part of the confusion comes from not realizing that **every** positive integer has a **unique** decomposition as a square times a product of different primes (product over a possibly empty set of primes).