# pythagorean triples reverse calculation

Tags: euclidean-geometry

what if i wanted to calculate m,n where C= 5 , for example

$$
a = 2np;
b= m2 -n2;
c = m2 + n2;
$$

let's say i want to start with c=5 instead of a m > n > 0 , how can i calculate m and n which created the values for a = 2mn , b= m2 -c2   , c = m2 + n2  = 5?

Comment: Rewrite your question. Still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution of $c=m^2+n^2$ for given $c$ by using the construction for Fermat's result to represent a number as a sum of two squares, i.e., following the construction given in the answer here:

[Prove that $n$ is a sum of two squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29441/prove-that-n-is-a-sum-of-two-squares)

For $n=5$ this is trivial. We can take $m=2$ and $n=1$. Note that there need not exists integers $m$ and $n$ with $c=m^2+n^2$ in general.